# Aframe When I change from a scene to another, oculus controller not work

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr, oculusquest, webxr

I have a page where there is an embedded scene and the possibility to trigger to enter to another different scene in VR. When I trigger on the second one, it´s works fine, but when I exited this and try to enter VR the embedded scene, the oculus controller not work, it´s like freeze on (0,0,0) and not respond to track position or buttons. I need to press Oculus button to exit the scene through Oculus browser menu.

I tried to remove the entity that have oculus-touch-controls component and set a new one when you trigger enterVR from the embedded scene, also I tried to remove only the oculus-touch-controls component from the entity and set again but doesn´t work neither.

This embedded scene can´t be destroy when you enter the other scene, any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Without runnable code it will be hard to help. I recommend https://glitch.com/~aframe Best of luck.

Comment: After some research and tests, I found that the root of the problem is on tracked-controls-webxr from embedded scene which lost the reference from the XRInputSource when the second scene is rendered. So I decided to create the embedded scene directly with three.js because I think the problem is having 2 instances of AFRAME simultaneously.